# import keyword Chrome 60

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

I was looking forward to finally using the `import` keyword in chromium and in [NW.JS](https://nwjs.io/), but even tho [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) says Chrome 60 has support for it I still get "*unexpected token import*" when I try to use it. What's going on?

(experimental javascript flag is enabled)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [this](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5365692190687232), needs to be chrome 61+.

## UPDATE

It does work in Chrome 60, experimental-web-platform flag must be enabled. `import` does not work in the console though. Works out of the box in 61 and 62, `import` does not throw a parser error in the console in 61, 62.

Comment: @JohnSmith seems so. Either that or it's behind a different flag. I'm typing this on chrome 60 and trying an import gets the same error you have. I did a quick cntrl-f through the available flags for "module" and "import" and came up empty.

Comment: @JaredSmith what about "harmony"? -- Edit: It's behind the "Experimental Web Platform " flag https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

Comment: @JohnSmith bear in mind that MDN is a community sourced wiki. Not an infallible source of truth.

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's the experimental JavaScript flag the OP was talking about. Harmony is only mentioned in one other flag and it's enabled by default.

Comment: I think the mdn entry gets it's info from: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/ 
But even with the alternative script type I can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: @JohnSmith think your going to have to use beta, canary, or wait a few more months for it to hit stable.

Comment: @addyosmani must also be wrong... https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/859296190323597313/

Comment: @evolutionxbox that tweet is months old and from when Chrome 60 was canary. The very likely took that out of the release before it hit stable. Just to check I enabled that flag he references in the tweet (experimental-web-platform) and I still get the unexpected token parse error (linux). `import` works out of the box in 61 and 62 (OSX).

Comment: @JaredSmith yeah. I can corroborate that. Sigh.

Comment: The referenced blog post on MDN has actually a working livedemo: https://cdn.rawgit.com/jakearchibald/a298d5af601982c338186cd355e624a8/raw/aaa2cbee9a5810d14b01ae965e52ecb9b2965a44/
It works! But for some reason I can't replicate it.

Comment: @JohnSmith see my update. I was able to replicate locally but that flag has to be set.

Comment: Yeah me too. Maybe for people reading this later on you could put the link to it in the answer.